# How to call c# function from onChange in a html input of type range?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an html control in my asp.net web page that uses a range slider. I am wondering how I can get the current value of the slider, and how I can call a c# function in my code behind when the user changes the value.

`<input id="zoomBar" type="range" min="0.3" max="1.5" step="0.1" runat="server" onchange="zoomBar_Change" oninput="zoomBar_Change" />`

Comment: I apologize in advance for the wording of the question, I did not know how exactly to word it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an AJAX request. If you create a JS function such as

```
function onSliderChange(
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'PerformAction',
    data: '{ }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        //perform whatever action here
    }
});)
```

Replace PerformAction with the name of the method you are calling. Make sure that any parameters match. More information can he found here - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-call-C-Sharp-methodfunction-using-jquery-ajax/

Hope it helps!